# how to get a value of a field in django

Tags: django

I'm currently working on a django app like IMDB.com that have a Media ( contains tvshows and movies ) model and an Episode model with a one-to-many relationship between them to display these episodes at the TvShow page.

I managed to be able to show the episodes of a tvshow inside the page with:

```
def tvshow(request, tvshow_title):

  tvshow = get_object_or_404(Media, title=tvshow_title)

  episodes = Episode.objects.all().filter(is_published=True, tvshow=tvshow)

  context = {
      'tvshow': tvshow,
      'episodes': episodes
  }

  return render(request, 'media/tvshow.html', context)
```

and this worked perfectly fine but I also needed to display episodes based on season and this got me kinda confused how do I know how many seasons does a tv show have when there's no field for it in the Media model, but the Episode model had a season_number field, so I tried to get to query the last episode of a tv show based on the season_number:

```
latest_episode = Episode.objects.order_by('-season_number').filter(is_published=True, tvshow=tvshow)[:1]
```

and I managed to indeed get the episode but I don't know now how to get what is the number of the season in it.

I tried

```
seasons = latest_episode.season_number
```

and

```
seasons = latest_episode['season_number']
```

and neither of them worked. please tell me if there's a better way to do it and if this way is good let me know how to get the season_number. :)

Comment: can you print `latest_episode` and share the result?

Comment: Instead of `[:1]` use `.first()`.

Comment: also, you dont need `.all()` in `Episode.objects.all().filter(is_published=True, tvshow=tvshow)` (it is redundant because of `.filter()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `[:1]` returns a `QuerySet`, which is basically a list, and not a model instance (think of it as returning `[EPISODE]` instead of just `EPISODE`. This means that you dont have access to the episode's `season_number` attribute.

Try this:

```
latest_episode = Episode.objects.order_by('-season_number').filter(is_published=True, tvshow=tvshow).first()
```

and then you should be able to use `latest_episode.season_number`

Comment: also do you think there was a better way to do it? I'd be interested to know!